# Replace a HTML part with replace()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple userscript that looks like this right now:

```
var i, sig = document.getElementsByClassName('after_content');
for (i = 0; i < sig.length; i++)
    {
        var str = sig[i].innerHTML;
        var n = str.replace("<div style='height:250px;overflow: auto;", "<div style='height:100%;overflow:visible;");
    }
```

I tried to do this to see if it output the proper stuff I wanted to output;

```
var i, sig = document.getElementsByClassName('after_content');
for(i = 0; i < sig.length; i++) {
    console.log(sig[i].innerHTML);
}
```

And it would output the stuff inside the class('s) which from I wanted to edit a small part.
But when I tried the first code I posted (str.replace one) it won't edit it.

What the after_content contains:

```
    <div class="after_content">     
        <div style="height:250px;overflow: auto;">
            <blockquote class="signature restore"><div class="signaturecontainer">signature here</div></div></blockquote>
        </div>      
    </div>      
    <div class="cleardiv"></div>
</div>
```

The line from that ^ I want to edit is the;

```
<div style="height:250px;overflow: auto;">
```

.. one.

I'd really appreciate help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I'm not sure how I make the code look properly with the ">"* - you don't, code formatting is done by selecting the code and pressing CTRL+k (or, if you prefer to do it manually, by indenting all lines with 4 spaces and having an empty line before/after the block)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good question, but since you are working with javascript you should be using jQuery to be doing this in my opinion.

first, include jQuery in your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, when you are ready, give all your divs that you want to change the class "div_class" (`<div class="div_class" style="height:250px;overflow:auto;">...</div>`);

to use jQuery to change the CSS you just have to do this:

```
$('.div_class').css({
    height:100%;
    overflow:visible;
});
```

jquery.com

To do this is native javascript, without the need to import more libraries (like jQuery), just do it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < sig.length; i++) {
    if (sig[i].style.height == "250px" && sig[i].style.overflow == "auto"){
        sig[i].style.height = "100%";
        sig[i].style.overflow = "visible";
    }
}
```

Here is a working example of the code with native JS: http://jsfiddle.net/gdSQW/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I do not have access to edit the HTML/CSS hence why I need/want to make an userscript for it. I need to search&replace the <div> string due to it not having a id/class.

Comment: then you can use native javascript to do this, i will update the answer.

Comment: The problem with you original script is that you are just manupulating a script in the code (in javascript) and not changing the HTML code on the page.  The new code I wrote above actually changes the css of the page.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to use the one you posted but it still won't change. :/

Comment: The code should work, please check out this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gdSQW/3/

Comment: Check here; http://jsfiddle.net/gdSQW/6/ - That's what it looks like /: Hence why I wanted to replace the string <div style>

Comment: i see, since your div "after_content" is the parent container, you have to use the `.children` property of that container to get all of the inner divs.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/gdSQW/16/.